# get_channel returning NoneType

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to accomplish the relatively simple task of sending a message to an announcement channel when the bot connects and disconnects, but I am getting an error that NoneType object has no send attribute. I understand that the only way get_channel would return None is if the channel wasn't found but I copy pasted the channel ID from discord so I am not sure how it could be wrong.

The reason I am doing this is because although the bot is functional, I will have to manually turn it on/off until I get it hosted. I would rather people know automatically.

The code is intended to be in on_ready, but is in a test command for development. My main code is essentially as follows:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import discord_general as dg

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
# could not do intents.message_content, it said that didnt exist,
# although I understand it is in the docs
intents.messages = True


bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="!", help_command=dg.MyHelp())



@bot.command()
async def t(ctx):
    await dg.online(msg)
    await ctx.send("Done")

    

bot.run(os.getenv('TOKEN'))
```

The code in my imported file is this:

```
async def online_msg():
    channel = bot.get_channel(998723366473187378)
    await channel.send("hello")

    # I have also used discord.Client.get_channel() and
    # discord.Guild.get_channel()
```

All of which yield this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\tmalo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\Users\tmalo\Desktop\GitHub\Worm-bot\commands\Economy.py", line 20, in on_command_error
raise error
File "C:\Users\tmalo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
File "C:\Users\tmalo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\tmalo\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'

Is there something I am missing? I even tried to go through the server ID and iterate through all channels until a match, but I am getting the same issue there where my objects are NoneTypes rather than discord objects. Any help would be much appreciated.

*edit: rather than importing the code into the main file where on_ready is, I tried to run the bot with the code written directly in the main file and it worked. But I have more code than simply "send hello", which is why I want it a different file. This is the first time I am having this issue.

**edit: I decided to go with a different method of sending this message, so I no longer need assistance; however it was never resolved so if anyone figures out why I was having issues, please let me know. Thank you to anyone who contributed a solution.

Comment: Where are you getting the channels? Internal caches might not have been populated yet. Make sure the bot logs in before attempting to get something from the cache. If this is a task start it in `setup_hook` or `cog_load`.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) `get_channel`is a method of the `Client` class. Please show how `bot` is initialized so we can verify it's of said type.

Comment: @white All `Bot` classes inherit from `Client` so that shouldn't be a problem not to mention it would throw an attribute error if that was the issue.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: Please include a [mcve]

Comment: ive edited my question for you all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `discord.Object()` in order to acquire a reference to your channel.

Usage:

```
channel = discord.Object(998723366473187378)
await channel.send("Hello")
```

A more dynamic but less efficient way is the following:

```
for channel in bot.get_all_channels():
   if channel.name == "announcements":
       await channel.send("Hello")
```

*Note: Please make sure that you have set up your bot correctly and that you're running these operations properly. You can find helpful code examples here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/v2.0.1/examples

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The discord.Object() method returned the error "object" object doesn't have attribute "send".  The second method of iterating through all channels returned the same error as prior being NoneType has no attribute "send".

Comment: sorry no, the second method did not return anything at all, but I believe the same issue happened in that bot.get_all_channels was NoneType. No error was raised though